# Navigate within modal dialog using shell

Tags: shell, xamarin

I'm using shell to navigate in my Xamarin Forms app. I want my settings to be in a Modal dialog which is navigated to by calling PushModalAsync. In that settings page I want to navigate to other pages, eg password change. But since I'm not using NavigationPage I cannot get it to work.

How do one use Shell with Modal and navigate within that Modal page?

I can get it to work by setting my SettingsPage as a new MainPage. But then I don't get the modal navigation animation.

Comment: wrap your Settings page in a NavigationPage

Comment: @Jason using NavigationPage will probably solve the problem but then I will no longer use Shell which I want to use. But if I don't find any other solution NavigationPage will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

> using NavigationPage will probably solve the problem but then I will
>   no longer use Shell which I want to use.

I think wrap your `Settings` page in a `NavigationPage` would solve your problem. You can still use Shell after using NavigationPage.

For example, you can do some push actions in the `SettingPage`:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new BearDetailPage());
}
```

In the `BearDetailPage`, if you want to use Shell, you can dismiss the SettingPage by send a  message using`MessagingCenter`:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PopToRootAsync(false);
    MessagingCenter.Send<BearDetailPage>(this, "BackToShell");
}
```

And in the `SettingPage`, subscribe that message:

```
public SettingPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<BearDetailPage>(this, "BackToShell", (sender) =>
    {
        // Do something whenever the "BackToShell" message is received
        this.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    });
}
```

If you don't want the `navigationbar` in the `SettingPage`, you can just hide it.